# Automatic javascript type coercion

Tags: javascript

This has become more of a pondering about how javascript works, than an actual problem to fix.  In the case of a statement like

```
var str = 9 + " some words here";
```

The resultant str var would contain the value "9 some words here".  My question is what function does javascript use to automatically coerce the Number object '9' into a string to be concatenated with the String object " some words here", and is this function changeable/overrideable.

This started from me needing to output single digits with a preceding 0 on a page.  This was easy enough to accomplish with a quick prototype function on the Number object

```
Number.prototype.SpecialFormat = function() {
  if(this < 10) {
    return "0" + this;
  }
  else {
   return this.toString();
  }
};
```

And call it with a simple `(9).SpecialFormat() + " words here";`

But that got me wondering if I could overwrite the toString function on a Number with a

```
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
  if(this < 10) {
    return "0" + this;
  }
  else {
   return this;
  }
};
```

, and just let javascripts automatic conversion handle it for me, so I could use a standard `9 + " words here";` to get the same result "09 words here". This did not just implicitly work, I had to end up adding .toString to the 9 `(9).toString() + " words here"` (which upon taking a further look, would have resulted in some infinite loops).

So is there a way to override the built in functionality of a javascript native type ?

*Note: I realize this is likely a '**worst idea ever**'

Comment: See [the addition operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) (step 7), as well as [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) and "[ToString Applied to the Number Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1)". It appears that the abstract operation `ToString(number)` does not ever use `Number.prototype.toString` (it's the other way around, in fact).

Comment: I guess that is why I get the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error when I use String(this) in the toString prototype.

Comment: I assume that in this case JavaScript is constructed differently than other object-oriented languages where you can override operators applied to objects. It seems to me that string concatenation is done internally by the interpreter ignoring all overridden methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [addition operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) coerces its arguments to strings in step 7:

> - If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>
>   - Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)

The [ToString operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) has special rules for numbers, detailed under "[ToString Applied to the Number Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1)".

It appears that the abstract operation `ToString(number)` does not ever use `Number.prototype.toString`. In fact, ti's the other way around: the [default `Number.prototype.toString` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.2) employs the abstract numeric ToString algorithm. Thus, it's not possible to override the default behavior for the stringification of numbers during type coercion in ECMAScript 5, because there's no way to alter the language-defined ToString operation.

ToString *does* use the target's `toString` method when coercing *objects* to strings, but not number primitive values.

Answer (score 3):

*(not strictly an answer but I need some space)*

Be very careful with type coercion, especially when combining **primitive types** with their object counterparts because:

```
var n = 9;
typeof n; // "number"
n instanceof Number; // false!!

n = new Number(9);
n instanceof Number; // true, oh thank God
typeof n; // "object" what!!
```

Also, `toString` on `Number` doesn't actually work:

```
Number.prototype.toString = function () { return "foo" + this; };
var n = new Number(9);
"" + n; // "9", not "foo9"
```

---

A way to avoid this mess is by having:

```
var ns = {
    number: {
        specialFormat: function () /* .. */ }
    }
}

ns.number.specialFormat(9); // "09"
```

Comment: 'n = Number(9);' in the first code block should be 'n = new Number(9);'. Otherwise you're just calling the Number function to convert the parameter into a number primitive, which it already is. Therefore the two lines following it will be the same as the two lines before it.